# Why is my python Butterworth filter smoothing the signal spectrum (in frequency space)?

Tags: filter, scipy, filtering, signal-processing, butterworth

For a fluctuating time series I use a low pass butterworth filter to exclude high frequency noise in my analysis. It is implemented using scipy.signal butter and filtfilt functions.

```
def butter_lp(data, N, cutoff, df):
    b, a = butter(N, cutoff/(df*len(data)), btype='lowpass', output='ba')
    y = filtfilt(b, a, data)

    return y

def plot_response(N, cutoff, data, df):
    b, a = butter(N, cutoff/(df*len(data)), btype='lowpass', output='ba')
    w, h = freqz(b, a)
    plt.plot(w * (1/(2*dt)), 20 * log10(abs(h)), label='{0}, {1}'.format(forder,cutoff))
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.xlabel('Frequency [radians / second]')
    plt.ylabel('Amplitude [dB]')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.margins(0, 0.1)
    plt.grid(which='both', axis='both')
    plt.axvline(100, color='green')  # cutoff frequency
    #plt.show()
```

for completeness the input 'data' code looks something like

```
filtered["channel{0:02d}".format(ch)] = butter_lp(noiseelim(transpose(xbt[0][6])[ch-1][opint:clint]), forder, lpfreq, df)
```

Taking order 5 (bearing in mind it's applied twice) and a cutoff of 200kHz I see the expected attenuation of the signal above this cutoff frequency BUT ALSO the fluctuations of the signal (now in a noise floor region of the spectrum) are smoothed. Why? Can I/ should I avoid it?

[shared y plot showing on the left the original spectrum including noise floor and adjacent (right) the filtered spectrum showing a smoothed, attenuating tail in place of the noise floor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bBCf.png)

Comment: It looks like your plot (a log-log) doesn't match the code (y-axis in dB), and the cutoff in the plot appears to be at 100 KHz, but in a nutshell, yes this is expected and not something to worry about. You don't care what's happening to the spectrum in the stopband as long as it's far below where it originally was. (If you really care about the details: Butterworth filters' attenuation increases the further into the stopband you go, so its output will follow a constant decay. If you used an FIR filter (from `firls`, etc.), with flat-ish stopbands, you'd see a different stopband pattern.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the y label change, different ordering so will double check but the principle remains I think. What sort of physicist would I be to ignore the details?! It does matter if the filter doesnt behave as expected! But perhaps I wasnt clear - the attenuation isnt my worry (indeed it is intended) but the apparent smoothing so that where large fluctuations existed in the noisy region before, now they are all but gone for an attenuation of just one decade.

Comment: As a sanity check, I generated some random data and a 5-tap Butterworth filter and, indeed, on a log-scale (in dB), the fluctuations in the original data remain quite visible even as they decay: see https://gist.github.com/fasiha/ce7fd8774d3cb3a865160ce85fb2a26e (in Python, since Matlab's Butterworth stuff is in a toolbox…) for the code and example. I'm not really sure why you're seeing this…

Comment: Well. At least it's not just me!

Comment: Having followed up some more I think theres a simpler normalisation by hard-coding the Nyquist frequency. Then I think if we compare my cutoff fraction to yours (more like .2) it makes sense for there to be a longer tail with fluctuations in front. That said there are some samples of data for which it fluctuates all the way down and others where it tails.